# How to connect digital persona fingerprint device with an android

Tags: java, android, digital-persona-sdk

I want to connect digital persona fingerprint device with an Android. This means I need the app source code for Android.

Like this app:
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.digitalpersona.digitalpersona

```java
import com.digitalpersona.uareu.*; 

private void start_scanning() {
    try {
        // Pick first available reader
        ReaderCollection rc = UareUGlobal.GetReaderCollection();
        rc.GetReaders();
        r = rc.get(0);
        if (r==null)
            return;

        // Open Reader
        r.Open(Reader.Priority.COOPERATIVE);
        System.out.println(r.GetStatus().status); // Outputs READY

        // The following call just hangs and never returns...
        Reader.CaptureResult
                cr = r.Capture(Fid.Format.ISO_19794_4_2005, Reader.ImageProcessing.IMG_PROC_DEFAULT, 500, -1);
        System.out.println(cr.quality.name()); // Just to test

    } catch (UareUException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

contact with

```
 ReaderCollection rc = UareUGlobal.GetReaderCollection();
        rc.GetReaders();
```

http://digital.persona.sdk.android.brainwaveappstudio.com/